# apache2: how to log to mysql server

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I have installed `apache2` server and configured a site with the file `site.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This logs the accessed pages to the file `access.log`. Besides this logging, I would like to create another logging like the one in `CustomLog`.

However, I would like to log it to a `mysql` database. I know about piping in the `CustomLog` directive... Is this the way? How may I do this logging?

Note: I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35 and Apache/2.4.29

Comment: THis guide shows how to exactly do that, no need over complicate things like piping. https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-logging-to-a-mysql-database-with-mod_log_sql-on-debian-etch

Comment: The `mod-log-sql` (version 100) has errors and its of very difficult configuration due to its errors. By the way, it is very old!!!!!!! Is there anything better? By the way, we are in 2021!!! Are `apache2` and/or `mysql` outdated? Till now I have not managed it to write to the database...